# Node.js changing path to static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I am other route everything is Ok, but when a subpage is being created dynamically I get an error 500 and I do not have favicon or my js file. Why is this happening?

```
- My route
app.get("/:id/vehicle", isLoggedIn,  (req, res) => {
  res.render("vehicle", { name: req.user }); <- edited, thanks
});

- Error message, code 500
GET http://localhost:3000/xxx/common/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED

- Path to public directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + "/public/favicon.ico"));
```

Comment: You are mising a closing `)` here: `res.render("vehicle", { name: req.user };`

Comment: @Fenton Thanks for pointing that out! It didn't solve my problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

Answer (score 1):

missing bracket is may be the issue.

```
res.render("vehicle", { name: req.user }); // you missed the closing ')' here
```

Comment: Thanks, but It's not a solution